# How do you create a nested binding scope in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

A Vue instance can allow you to create nested view models. For example, consider the following

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      firstName: "Joe",
      lastName: "Bloggs"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    name: function () {
        return this.form.firstName + ' ' + this.form.lastName;
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see, there is a nested form-data object: form.firstName and form.lastName. I can bind this view-model to HTML with the following:

```
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <label>
      First:
      <input type="text" v-model="form.firstName">
    </label>
    <label>
      Last:
      <input type="text" v-model="form.lastName">
    </label>
  </form>
  <div>
    You are: {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a JS Fiddle for this Vue.js example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf4y3dav/1/)

Now, my question is: is there a simple way (e.g. a directive) to create a nested binding scope that allows me to address firstName and lastName without the preceding "form."?

Knockout.js has the [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) that allows you to explicitly specify a binding scope in relationship to your view-model. [Here is a JS Fiddle showing Knockout.js using the with binding](https://jsfiddle.net/94ynz6nm/8/)

Is there a simple analogue to Knockout's [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) in Vue?

Comment: as far as I know, no way. You can address to firstName and lastName only by preceding "form". Btw, example in vue looks simpler than in knockout.

Comment: As @NazgulMamasheva pointed out, you can't do it exactly like that. However, you can always make the form a stand-alone component and pass it the form data object as a prop.

Comment: @janfoeh What about creating a custom component and pass the form properties as a prop in that component and dynamically create the inputs ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I'm doing something similar now, yeah. Splatting a passed-in prop in `data()` works like a charm.

Comment: @janfoeh Do you want me to create a demo for this ? Or you already did that ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I'm on it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this behavior by using the composition API function [`reactive`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) and the utility [`toRefs`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs) with `setup` option as follows :

```html
<script>
import { reactive, toRefs, computed } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const form = reactive({
      firstName: "aa",
      lastName: "bb",
    });

    const name = computed(() => form.firstName + " " + form.lastName);

    return { ...toRefs(form), name };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form>
      <label>
        First:
        <input type="text" v-model="firstName" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last:
        <input type="text" v-model="lastName" />
      </label>
    </form>
    <div>You are: {{ name }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNkk2PnDAMhv+KlQuMlgl3xKzUS09VD71VyiUDpmVFPpSY6VaI/75OgNkP7WGFRGzHeWK/8SK+eS9vM4pGtLELoyd4VBZgNN4FgiWg7mi8YUXuFw6x6pzxM2G/whCcgYKPFsric87ucdDzREsCRKTZl6dsA3TORoLBBQMXOJjlvgkwjCHST22wKbQuqiM86SN6vfItKbSetvUt1nLK5SisLE+Xx3SRvEPhAQr+HvL98oC+AwWuNthFSrn1WabUU5XIa8rIP2V5aetNJlaJHULjJ03IXtuPNxj7ixLaeyWyim3CZIvtSV9x2h2A76m65vDa0XL1QP89MoDwmZSA29m4HicO3FvZuXygfov7wP7BLX4VfcjxKbmt7w2k9vaM324GHbCBZckCZXHaekt4Xe/aiEps43Q22sun6CxPW357tW9EJZi2P4jgmUq+En+JfGzqOg5dmtGnKF34U7Mlw2xpNCgxmvM1uH8RA4OV2N9qFesLSJjuhQ==)**

in `script setup` syntax just destruct the object returned from `toRefs` and properties will be exposed directly to the template :

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs, computed } from "vue";

const form = reactive({
  firstName: "aa",
  lastName: "bb",
});

const name = computed(() => form.firstName + " " + form.lastName);

const { firstName, lastName } = toRefs(form);
</script>
```

### Options API example

This is an example of splatting/spreading a `prop` inside a component into `data` attributes. It uses a "model object" containing the data, which is likely unidiomatic Vue code, but might be more familiar to people coming from KnockoutJS:

```js
const { createApp, ref, markRaw } = Vue;

class MyModelObject {
  constructor() {
    this.valueA = ref();
    this.valueB = ref();
    
    // prevent Vue from making instances of this class
    // deeply reactive when they are assigned to the root
    // components `data`
    markRaw(this);
  }
};

const MyComponent = {
  props: {
    object: Object
  },
  data() {
    return { ...this.object };
  },
  template: document.querySelector("template")
};

createApp({
  components: {
    MyComponent: MyComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      object: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.object = new MyModelObject();

    this.object.valueA.value = "foo";
    this.object.valueB.value = "bar";
  }
}).mount(document.querySelector("main"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<main>
  <my-component :object="object"></my-component>
</main>

<template>
  {{ valueA }} {{ valueB }}
</template>
```

Comment: Lovely - this works just as well with the options API, which I am using. Simply destructuring a passed-in `prop` in `data()` seems to have been enough. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, How have you done that in Options API?

Comment: I've added an example to your answer - I hope you don't mind. If you do mind, for example because what I have written is too unidiomatic VueJS code, please revert my edit by all means.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have repeated values, you could alias it to a computed property like

```
computed: {
  firstName: function() {
    return form.firstName
  },
  lastName: function() {
    return form.lastName
  }
}
```